# Join unsorted files on the second field

Tags: linux, bash, unix, join, awk

I am just tired of using the `join` command and not getting the desired result, and it returns some error.

One more thing I've read all queries related to the `join` command here and in SuperUser also, but couldn't get success.

How can I use `join` or `awk`?

```
file1.csv
autoid|Mycolumn
5|Odhav, Gujarat, 380010
7|Navrangpura, Gujarat, 380009
16|Kalupur, Gujarat, 380002
32|Naroda, Gujarat, 380025
62|Khamasa, Gujarat, 380001
73|Sola Road, Gujarat, 380063
74|Railwaypura, Gujarat, 380002
78|Meghaninagar, Gujarat, 380016
85|Thaltej, Gujarat, 380054

file2.csv
5|Odhav, Gujarat, 380010|22.406347|73.824345
7|Navrangpura, Gujarat, 380009|22.328403|73.881841
16|Kalupur, Gujarat, 380002|22.379901|73.814217
32|Naroda, Gujarat, 380025|22.417059|73.887806
38|Raikhad, Gujarat, 380001|22.491544|73.782878
39|Ashram Road, Gujarat, 380006|22.279248|73.846393
44|Raipur, Gujarat, 380002|22.346186|73.87462
56|Jamalpur, Gujarat, 380022|22.518504|73.785024
58|Patharkuva, Gujarat, 380001|22.308473|73.825071
62|Khamasa, Gujarat, 380001|22.100711|73.707207
73|Sola Road, Gujarat, 380063|22.026236|73.732926
74|Railwaypura, Gujarat, 380002|21.992994|73.86893
78|Meghaninagar, Gujarat, 380016|21.955106|73.878629
85|Thaltej, Gujarat, 380054|21.989253|73.735725
```

I am using this command but couldn't get desired result:

```
$ join -t'|' -1 2 -2 2 <(sort -k2 Areaprob.csv) <(sort -k2 Com_remoteArea.csv)>output.csv
```

It returns something like this; as you can see, I'm already using the `sort` command with `join` as given above.

```
join: file 1 is not in sorted order
join: file 2 is not in sorted order
```

My `output.csv` looks like this - and it doesn't return all 9 records as `file1.csv`

```
Mycolumn|autoid|autoid|Gis_lat|Gis_long
Khamasa, Gujarat, 380001|62|62|22.100711|73.707207
Railwaypura, Gujarat, 380002|74|74|21.992994|73.86893
Thaltej, Gujarat, 380054|85|85|21.989253|73.735725
Sola Road, Gujarat, 380063|73|73|22.026236|73.732926
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to tell `sort` the delimiter. Try with `sort -t'|' -k2`:

```
$ join -t'|' -j2 <(sort -t'|' -k2 file1) <(sort -t'|' -k2 file2)
Kalupur, Gujarat, 380002|16|16|22.379901|73.814217
Khamasa, Gujarat, 380001|62|62|22.100711|73.707207
Meghaninagar, Gujarat, 380016|78|78|21.955106|73.878629
Naroda, Gujarat, 380025|32|32|22.417059|73.887806
Navrangpura, Gujarat, 380009|7|7|22.328403|73.881841
Odhav, Gujarat, 380010|5|5|22.406347|73.824345
Railwaypura, Gujarat, 380002|74|74|21.992994|73.86893
Sola Road, Gujarat, 380063|73|73|22.026236|73.732926
Thaltej, Gujarat, 380054|85|85|21.989253|73.735725
```

Note: You can use `-j2` as you are joining on field 2 in both files.

---

**Edit:**

You will need `awk` if you want to keep the heading:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==1;FNR==NR{a[$2];next}$2 in a{print $2,$3,$4}' OFS='|' file1 file2
autoid|Mycolumn
Odhav, Gujarat, 380010|22.406347|73.824345
Navrangpura, Gujarat, 380009|22.328403|73.881841
Kalupur, Gujarat, 380002|22.379901|73.814217
Naroda, Gujarat, 380025|22.417059|73.887806
Khamasa, Gujarat, 380001|22.100711|73.707207
Sola Road, Gujarat, 380063|22.026236|73.732926
Railwaypura, Gujarat, 380002|21.992994|73.86893
Meghaninagar, Gujarat, 380016|21.955106|73.878629
Thaltej, Gujarat, 380054|21.989253|73.735725
```

Comment: thanks..! can I  get output without disturbing the row order of file1.csv with header. please help...!

Comment: @user1586957 yes I have added an `awk` script to do this. If this solves your problem please accept this answer by clicking the tick mark next to the answer.

Comment: Nice solution! But it can be done with `join` as well using `head` and `tail` commands. It would be not this nice as it would use a lot of processes instead of a single awk.

Answer (score 1):

does this help?

```
awk -F'|' -vOFS="|" 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} $1FS$2 in a{print $2,$3,$4}' file1 file2
```

or

```
 awk -F'|' -vOFS="|" 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} $1 in a{print $2,$3,$4}' file1 file2
```

the two awk oneliners above give same
output based on your current example input. (without title):

```
Odhav, Gujarat, 380010|22.406347|73.824345
Navrangpura, Gujarat, 380009|22.328403|73.881841
Kalupur, Gujarat, 380002|22.379901|73.814217
Naroda, Gujarat, 380025|22.417059|73.887806
Khamasa, Gujarat, 380001|22.100711|73.707207
Sola Road, Gujarat, 380063|22.026236|73.732926
Railwaypura, Gujarat, 380002|21.992994|73.86893
Meghaninagar, Gujarat, 380016|21.955106|73.878629
Thaltej, Gujarat, 380054|21.989253|73.735725
```

title is fixed text, you can add by yourself.

Comment: @user1586957 it first save the first column of file1 into an array, then for each line of file2, check if the first column in that array, if true, print.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the delimiter for `sort` as well. The below should work:

```
join -t'|' -1 2 -2 2 <(sort -t '|' -k2 Areaprob.csv) <(sort -t'|' -k2 Com_remoteArea.csv) > output.csv
```

Your sort command sorts the file starting from the second column, and not starting after '|' .

Comment: thanks..! can I get output without disturbing the row order of file1.csv with header. please help...!